# Summarize columns when Footable is in small devices

Tags: html, css, footable

I have a table and I want to summarize some of the values in the columns when I show that table in small devices.

Lets suppose I have this table (Big Devices)

```
Process   Good   Bad   Rework  Total
P1          10     5        2     17
P2           5     3        2     10
Total        5     8        4     17
```

When I show this table in Small Devices I would like to show this

```
Process   Good   Other  Total
P1          10       7     17 +
P2           5       5     10 +
Total        5      12     17 +
```

But I don't want to show the "Other" column in big devices (and I don't want to show the + symbol either).  I want that column totally hidden.

I can't find how to achieve that.  Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSS Media Queries**.

Have a look at the snippet below (*Use full-screen mode for desktop - to show bad & rework cells*):

```css
th, td {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.visible-mob {
  display: none;
  background: #FF0;
}

.hidden-mob {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #38E8F1;
}

/* When Screen Width is >= 767px ( ~ Mobile Devices) */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .visible-mob {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  
  .hidden-mob {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Process</th>
      <th>Good</th>
      <th class="hidden-mob">Bad</th>
      <th class="hidden-mob">Rework</th>
      <th class="visible-mob">Other</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>P1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td class="hidden-mob">5</td>
      <td class="hidden-mob">2</td>
      <td class="visible-mob">7</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>P2</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td class="hidden-mob">3</td>
      <td class="hidden-mob">2</td>
      <td class="visible-mob">5</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td class="hidden-mob">8</td>
      <td class="hidden-mob">4</td>
      <td class="visible-mob">12</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer works perfect when you use regular HTML tables but if you use footable, tables behavior changes and this does not apply because footable applies styles inline and uses data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ugly hack I applied to achieve temporarily what I want to do.  If someone finds a better way please let me know.

HTML

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Process</th>
      <th>Good</th>
      <th data-breakpoints="xs">Bad</th>
      <th data-breakpoints="xs">Rework</th>
      <th class="visible-column visible-column-sm" data-classes="visible-column visible-column-sm" data-visible="false">Other</th>
      <th>Total</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>P1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>P2</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.visible-column {
    display: none !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .visible-column-sm {
         display: table-cell !important;
    }
}
```

At the end of the HTML

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.table').footable();
    });
</script>
```

Here is the Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/oL7m7uqq/